# Categorical classification in Keras Python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, multiclass-classification

I am doing multi-class classification of 5 classes. I am using Tensorflow with Keras. My code is like this:

```
# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("Data5Class.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:47].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,47]
print("Load Data.....")

encoder= to_categorical(Y)

def create_larger():  
    model = Sequential()
    print("Create Dense Ip & HL 1 Model ......")
    model.add(Dense(47, input_dim=47, kernel_initializer='normal',     activation='relu'))
    print("Add Dense HL 2 Model ......")
    model.add(Dense(40, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    print("Add Dense output Model ......")
    model.add(Dense(5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimators = []
estimators.append(('rnn', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_larger, epochs=60,  batch_size=10, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, encoder, cv=kfold)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

The CSV file I have taken as an input contains the data with labels. The labels are like this `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` which represent 5 different classes.

1. Then, as the labels are already in integer form, do I need to use
   the `LabelEncoder()` function in my code?
2. Also, I have used `to_categorical(Y`) function. Should I use it or I should just pass the Y variable containing these labels to the classifier for training?
3. I got the error like this:
   Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead.
   This error occurred when I used encoder variable in the code
         results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, encoder, cv=kfold) where encoder variable represents the to_categorical(Y) data. How to solve this error?

Comment: No need to use LabelEncoder(). But usage of `to_categorical()` depends on the loss function used in the Keras model. Show that code.

Comment: Yes. I have used categorical_crossentropy loss function. The code is like this: 
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: You cannot use the Keras estimator with StratifiedKFold in the cross_val_score. You need to write a custom cross validation for that, in which the data passed to StratifiedKFold should be original `y` and then after splitting it should be encoded with `to_categorical()` and pass to Keras.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [Keras documentation here](https://keras.io/losses/):

> Note: when using the categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets
>   should be in categorical format (e.g. if you have 10 classes, the
>   target for each sample should be a 10-dimensional vector that is
>   all-zeros except for a 1 at the index corresponding to the class of
>   the sample). In order to convert integer targets into categorical
>   targets, you can use the Keras utility to_categorical:
>
> ```
> from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
> categorical_labels = to_categorical(int_labels, num_classes=None)
> ```

So this means that you need to use the `to_categorical()`  method on your `y` before training. But no need to use LabelEncoder if `y` is already in integer type.

Comment: Yes Sir. I tried using only to_categorical(Y) in my code. But, if I use only this and try running it. It shows error.                                           ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead.

Comment: Therefore, I did not include the to_categorical(Y). Will it give correct accuracy results then ?

Comment: @AmulyaDixit On which code are you getting the error "Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead. ". Please edit the question. And, no you will not get correct results if you dont include the to_categorical

Comment: seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("Data.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.valuesX = dataset[:,0:47].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,47]

Comment: @AmulyaDixit Dont post here. Edit the question

Comment: @Ashery Mbilinyi refile for the correction and paste string below OP Vivek original answer. How you did it violates the answer. Your improvement was at the wrong place.  **UPDATE :** For Keras 2.2.4 use `from keras.utils import to_categorical`.